# Can you make a button with a command that would re-run your code in TkInter?

Tags: python, tkinter, widget

Let's say I want to make a TkInter button that would restart or re-run the entire code for example:

```py
restart_button = tk.Button(root, text = "Re-Run", command = whatever the code is or function to restart)
```

I don't want anything complicated just a simple function or answer will be fine.

Answer (score 2):

Try using this code:

```
import sys
import os
from tkinter import Tk, Label, Button

def restart_program():
    """Restarts the current program.
    Note: this function does not return. Any cleanup action (like
    saving data) must be done before calling this function."""
    python = sys.executable
    os.execl(python, python, * sys.argv)

root = Tk()

Label(root, text="Hello World!").pack()
Button(root, text="Restart", command=restart_program).pack()

root.mainloop()
```

If you have any questions feel free to comment here.

Comment: it stops the program and doesn't actually re-runs it though